# Xcode 10 on macbook- How to comment /* */ with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: c, xcode10

I'm using Xcode 10 on macbook for writing C program. How can I make a block of comment with keyboard shotcut like this example:

```
/*
 * class.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 30, 2019
 *      Author: abbn
 */
```

I know how to comment with: cmd + / but it creates comments with // and not /*

Comment: For professional use, you should rather copy/paste the source header required by your internal coding standard, instead of some auto-generated goo. Proper source documentation matters a lot.

Comment: I actually need for commenting in the code itself, do describe functions for example.

Comment: In a professional project, you would have templates for function documentation as well.

Comment: when coding it helps to comment and uncomment parts of the code

Answer (score 0):

Select the block of code you want to comment and press `CTRL + Shift + /` for Windows or `Control + Shift + /` for Macintosh.

For uncommenting, use `CTRL + Shift + \` for Windows, or `Control + Shift + \` for Macintosh.